# SP2010 Selected View dropdown limit

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, list-view

Is there a way to change the item limit on the selected view drop-down list provided when you edit a list view webpart?

Comment: could you please give us more information about it, what you mean by change the item limit? if possible add the screen shots...you can modify any view you have access and change the item limit

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in Sharepoint 2013 I guess. This is the situation. You create a page that shows the web part of a list. If you edit the web part, you get the option to select another list view from a drop-down menu titled 'Selected View'. Normally this works fine, but if you have too many list views on the same list, the drop-down menu only shows a limited amount (in my case 47 custom made views and 5 of the standard views). The question from the OP was whether there is a possibility to show all possible list view in the drop-down.

Sorry for replying on an old post like this, but I'm really stuck.

[image: Screen shot of the list view selector]